# (De)Serializing objects automatically to a bundle

Tags: android, scala, serialization, deserialization

I've seen some libraries in Scala that can (de)serialize automatically any case class that has supported member types automatically to i.e. [JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23531065/scala-parse-json-directly-into-a-case-class).

In the Android world, I'd like to be able to do so with Intent and Bundle.

Example, I'd like this boilerplate code to be generated:

```
case class Ambitos(idInc: Long, idGrupo: String, ambitos: Map[String, Seq[String]])
    def serialize(b: Bundle) {
        b.putString("grupo", idGrupo)
        b.putLong("inc", idInc)
        b.putStringArray("ambitos", ambitos.keys.toArray)
        ambitos.foreach { case (a, det) ⇒
            b.putStringArray(a, det.toArray)
        }
    }

    def serialize(b: Intent) {
        b.putExtra("grupo", idGrupo)
        b.putExtra("inc", idInc)
        b.putExtra("ambitos", ambitos.keys.toArray)
        ambitos.foreach { case (a, det) ⇒
            b.putExtra(a, det.toArray)
        }
    }
}

object Ambitos {
    def apply(b: Intent): Ambitos =
        Ambitos(b.getLongExtra("inc", -1), b.getStringExtra("grupo"),
            b.getStringArrayExtra("ambitos").map{ a ⇒ (a, b.getStringArrayExtra(a).toSeq) }.toMap)

    def apply(b: Bundle): Ambitos =
        Ambitos(b.getLong("inc"), b.getString("grupo"),
            b.getStringArray("ambitos").map{ a ⇒ (a, b.getStringArray(a).toSeq) }.toMap)
}
```

Does exist such a library or do I have to make it by myself?

For passing complex information between Activities and for handling [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()`, this tool would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer that Nick has provided me in a [Android Scala forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-on-android/x9c1hv3IdTo):

It should be relatively straightforward if you know your way around macros :)
[Here’s one](https://github.com/macroid/macroid/blob/master/src/main/scala/macroid/Bundles.scala#L24) that serializes pairs `(key, value)`.

From there, you just need to add the case class inspection bit. [Example](https://github.com/jto/validation/blob/master/validation-core/src/main/scala/play/api/data/mapping/MappingMacros.scala#L41) (a bit convoluted), see also line 89 for usage.
On a final note, I would make it typeclass-based rather than inheritance-based:

```
trait Bundleable[A] {
  def toBundle(x: A): Bundle
  def fromBundle(b: Bundle): Try[A]
}

implicit def genBundleable[A]: Bundleable[A] = macro ???

def bundle[A: Bundleable](x: A) =
  implicitly[Bundleable[A]].toBundle(x)
```

This way you can define instances of `Bundleable[A]` both manually and automatically. And your data model is not polluted with Android nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

you can use GSON lib to do something different, I assume you have some complex object and you  want to pass from one activity to another activity.

just use GSON

```
Gson gson = new Gson();     
// convert java object to JSON format,  
// and returned as JSON formatted string  
String jsonString = gson.toJson(complexJavaObj);
```

and then just use

```
i.putExtra("objectKey",jsonString);
```

and read as in second activity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
String jsonString = extras.getString("objectKey");

 if(jsonString!=null){
   Gson gson = new Gson();
   ComplexJavaObj complexJavaObj= gson.fromJson(jsonString, ComplexJavaObj .class);
  }
}
```

Hope this will give you the basic idea.

Comment: It's an easy alternative to serialize to JSON, and then the resulting String to a Bundle.  I'm not sure, if it is the best in performance.

Comment: Another benefit is that the same code serves for serializing from/to Intent's and Bundle's.

Comment: new Gson().toJson(new Bundle()); -> this line gives a StackOverflow crash on Android 6