# GSON deserialize to bundle

Tags: android, json, gson, parcelable

How can i deserialize this JSON:

```
"data": {
    "key1": 11,
    "key2": {
        "key3": 22
        "key4": 83
        "key5": 99
    }
}
```

to an Android Bundle using GSON library? This is not working:

```
class Model implements Parcelable {

    private int key1;
    private Bundle key2;

        [...]

    protected Model(Parcel in) {
        key1 = in.readInt();
        [...]
        key2 = in.readBundle();
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(key1);
        [...]
        dest.writeBundle(key2);
    }
}
```

I don't want to create a key2 model.

Comment: check this post. I think it will answer your question ;). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26501968/deserializing-objects-automatically-to-a-bundle

Answer (score 0):

ok, I can write an example to this likeness to your question..

I believe your keys would be changing as what you have asked in the question is not the same as what you actually want, so I created a `Key` class and you can change it to appropriate class `Object` which you need to get.

> Key.java

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Key {

    @SerializedName("key")
    private String key;

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
}
```

> Data.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Data {

    @SerializedName("someName")
    private String someKey;

    @SerializedName("Key")
    private Key key;

    @SerializedName("keys")
    private ArrayList<Key> keys;

    public String getSomeKey() {
        return someKey;
    }

    public void setSomeKey(String someKey) {
        this.someKey = someKey;
    }

    public Key getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(Key key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public ArrayList<Key> getKeys() {
        return keys;
    }

    public void setKeys(ArrayList<Key> keys) {
        this.keys = keys;
    }
}
```

you can test this with following code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Key key = new Key();
    key.setKey("someNumber");

    ArrayList<Key> keys = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Key key2 = new Key();
        key2.setKey("1"+i);
        keys.add(key2);
    }

    Data data = new Data();
    data.setKey(key);
    data.setKeys(keys);

    String result =(new Gson()).toJson(data);

    System.out.println(result);

    System.out.println("\n#######\n");

    Data data2 = (new Gson()).fromJson(result, Data.class);

    System.out.println(data2.getKey().getKey());
}
```

this is just an example where the class `Data` has been converted in `JSON` and than deserialized to get it's object populated, this should get you an idea about how to read your own data.

> Output

```
{"Key":{"key":"someNumber"},"keys":[{"key":"10"},{"key":"11"},{"key":"12"},{"key":"13"},{"key":"14"}]}

#######

someNumber
10
11
12
13
14
```